# Creating own Auth Driver in FuelPHP

Tags: php, database, authentication, fuelphp

Last 2 days I was searching how to build my own Auth Driver in FuelPHP. 
We need to check some users from other table because of old datas in our database.

So, I need to write my own Auth Driver. First of all, I really don't know where I should start. Is it possible to build new Auth Driver from SimpleAuth(w/ extends)?

Could someone help me what I should do, I'll be really appreciating..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the Auth Docs: [Writing your own drivers](http://docs.fuelphp.com/packages/auth/drivers.html)

Comment: Actually there is not enough info for it. Last 3 day, i spent whole my time to create my Auth Library. And basically start with duplicate SimpleAuth library with another name.. And start to change inside of it. But that took a lot of time of mine to understand..